# HTTP POST to External API with Basic Credentials (SP2013)

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, rest

I'm trying to create a workflow in Sharepoint Designer which utilizes the HTTP Web Service action to send data to a non-Sharepoint API. (in my case, Leankit: https://support.leankit.com/entries/20265038-API-Basics )

I've made calls like this with javascript in the past, but I need this to be server-side. I have no .net experience, so I figured I'd give this a try. However, all of the tutorials I've found are more focused on posting data between Sharepoint sites. Is it possible to send data somewhere else? Are there any guides on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post from Fabian has a great comparison of an HTTP call in Fiddler to SPD. (Even though his target is SharePoint, the concepts remain the same.)

http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2013/09/04/using-the-call-http-web-service-rest-calls-in-sharepoint-online-using-spd/